# How to manually enter latitude and longitude for a PointField in Django admin with OSMGeoAdmin or GeoModelAdmin?

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I enter the latitude and longitude of a `PointField` when creating/editing an entry using the `OSMGeoAdmin` or `GeoModelAdmin`? Currently, I have a map where I can place the point by clicking on the map. I'd like to keep this behavior but also be able to manually specify the exact values.

[image: Editing point field with OSMGeoAdmin]

**Details**

I have a `Location` model with a `PointField` attribute.

```py
# models.py
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    point = PointField(blank=True, null=True)
```

```py
# admin.py
from django.contrib.gis.admin import OSMGeoAdmin

@admin.register(Location)
class LocationAdmin(OSMGeoAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "name")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do so using LeafletGeoAdmin.

```
# admin.py
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin

@admin.register(Location)
class LocationAdmin(LeafletGeoAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "name")
    settings_overrides = {
       'DEFAULT_CENTER': (49.474182, 10.988509),
       'DEFAULT_ZOOM': 15,
    }
    display_raw = True
```